# Eclipse/Git: "You're using an RSA key with SHA-1, which is no longer allowed. Please use a newer client or a different key type."

Tags: git, eclipse

I created a public key in Git using `ssh-keygen` which was successfully created as `.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.

[image]

I then uploaded it to GitHub in my SSH Keys, and "Authorized" its SSO feature. Everything is uploaded now.

[image]

When cloning a repository in Eclipse, I get the following message
[image]

Comment: Ugh, using SourceTree 4.2.5 to generate an ssh key (using the handy "Generate Key" button in the Accounts modal) and connect to github (sourcetree even uploaded the key for me) yields this error.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

According to Github security blog `RSA` keys with SHA-1 are no longer accepted.

Use the following command to create new SSH key with `ECDSA`encryption and add it to Github.

`ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 521 -C "your_email@example.com"`

Original answer with details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71498991/7544704)

Comment: Thanks, but what about an RSA which is not SHA-1? Is that possible? The ECDSA worked.

Comment: I second this question -- need an RSA key for OpsWorks, which seems to not accept anything else.

Comment: Works with cpanel ( terminal ), Thanks

Comment: or simply `ssh-keygen -t ecdsa`

Answer (score 11):

I had to generate an **ECDSA** key, not an **RSA** key. Not sure why, but none of the RSA options worked for me, including the default.

```
ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 256 -m PEM
```

I got this from
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71502531/1005607

Then I uploaded it to GitHub (after deleting my old key first), updated my Eclipse SSH2 private key to point to `id_ecdsa`. Now I can clone repositories.

Comment: In Eclipse you can create an SSH key which will work with GitHub in the preferences _General > Network Connections > SSH2_ tab _Key Management_ by hitting the _Generate RSA Key..._ button. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68802292/6505250

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it **didn't work**. None of the RSA options, including Eclipse-generated ones, worked. Only the ECDSA one did. They must have changed something recently in Git. Actually, just yesterday someone posted a similar question, and this is where I got the answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71489256/spring-cloud-config-server-github-sha-1-error/

Comment: The responder in that thread noted, " *all* RSA keys get the same error about SHA-1 signing" -- so he had to go with something different entirely (ECDSA).

Comment: As of March 15, 2022, GitHub no longer accepts newly uploaded RSA keys with SHA-1: https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/

Answer (score 2):

you can follow this steps To solve this problem :

in your terminal type this command ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 521 -C "your_email@example.com"
you will be ask:

-"enter file in which To save the key" click enter

-enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase) click enter again

- enter same passphrase again click enter

you will a message "your public key vas been saved in /user/machine/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub(just an example ).

-type cat (where the file was save in my case /user/machine/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub) To see your new generate ecdsa key .copy and  go to github create a new ssh (dont forget to remove the old one ) and paste it then save

in your terminal again type ssh-add (directory of your new created id_ecdsa) to add it to the list. you will see identity added : directory of your key

hope this was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Small remark I had to first delete old key from my github account. I am not sure if it was just some coincidence.

Comment: I updated my answer to mention deleting the old key first.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub improved security by dropping older, insecure key types on March 15, 2022.

Paste the text below in your terminal and substituting in your GitHub email address.

```
$ ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

More Details Follow GitHub Docs : [Generate new SSH key](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)